# Generate personal access token in github using api

Tags: github-api

Is there any way I can login to my github account via my username and password and generate personal access token using api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. With reference to GitHub documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#authentication I got it passed and able to make a python script that can serve my purpose.

Here is what should work (Postman example):

```
POST https://mycloud.example.com/api/v3/authorizations
{
  "note" : "example-1",
  "scopes" : [
    "repo"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, please use Basic Auth and provide your valid username and password.

Comment: The documentation is here but as stated earlier it is deprecated: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/rest/reference/oauth-authorizations#create-a-new-authorization

Answer (score 9):

***UPDATE:*** per this [blog post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-oauth-auth-endpoint/), they've deprecated the [OAuth Authorizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/), that support generating personal access tokens.

so now, you'll have to generate it using the [web settings](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) page instead.

Original answer:

> **Calls to OAuth Authorizations API**
>
> If you're making OAuth Authorization API calls to manage your OAuth app's authorizations or to create personal access or OAuth tokens like:
>
> `curl -u my_username:my_password -X POST "https://api.github.com/authorizations" -d '{"scopes":["public_repo"], "note":"my token", "client_id":"my_client_id", "client_secret":"my_client_secret"}'`
>
> Then you must switch to the web application flow to generate access tokens.