# How to rotate Github API secrets automatically?

Tags: terraform, github-actions, github-api

So according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458669/generate-personal-access-token-in-github-using-api), the api to manage PATs and Client Secrets is dead. What I'm trying to do is have the client secrets stored in my Github Actions Secrets rotated automatically.

One secret stored in Action Secrets is a Cloud Service Provider (CSP, ex: Azure) Client Secret. Its for terraform to manage the CSP resources. The other is a GH PAT/Client ID to save the Action Secrets when they are rotated by Terraform in an Action Cron.

As I see it, right now, I can either set super long (like three month) PAT/Client Secrets that get rotated manually on the Web Settings, or I can abandon using github Actions with Terraform and use something like Azure DevOps pipelines.

What is the process for automatically rotating github tokens (client id/PAT)?

Comment: Do you know if the generated $GITHUB_TOKEN for each workflow run can be used to add a secret to a repo instead if a PAT? If yes, you can achieve what you want using it with the Github API.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I don't, but I'll try it and see. Seems dangerous if it works, but that's something to explore if it works in the first place. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @GuiFalourd $GITHUB_TOKEN did not work. I used `https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-action-secret` and provided `token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` and it showed 403. Error indicates token did not have permissions to update secret. Tried it with a valid PAT token it worked.

Comment: Might OpenID Connect be helpful here? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect

Comment: @rethab wow I didn't know that option existed. Unfortunately, it still requires a client secret to be stored in the github action secrets. That means this particular secret will also expire at some point and need to be rotated. You can set the secret to never expire, but that takes security in the opposite direction I want it to go :)