# GitHub - generate fine-grained tokens via API

Tags: github, github-api, github-token

Is there any way of creating fine-grained PATs (personal access tokens) via GitHub's API? Or any other way of automating fine-grained PATs creation?

I did find some older questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458669/generate-personal-access-token-in-github-using-api) ) on the subject, but the answers only mention an older API, that is now deprecated.

The use case is this: I have multiple applications that read data from multiple GitHub repos. Each application can only read from specific repos, but this access should continue for a long time. So I need an easy(ier) way of generating the PATs, and rolling them over when they expire. What would be the best way of doing this?